# How can I transform a 3D triangle to xy plane

Tags: triangles, transformation, 3d

Suppose I am given a triangle ABC and its corresponding vertex coordinates in 3D. I want to transform ABC in such a way so that vertex A lies on global  (0,0,0) coordinate, B lies on (dist, 0, 0) where dist is the distance between A to B before transformation and  C lies on the xy plane.

How can I calculate the transformation for the above case? What would be the rotation and the translation component for such transformation?

Answer (score 3):

First, subtract the coordinates of A from those of all three vertices,
giving the translation (assuming translation is done before rotation --
they don't commute).

This gives vertices (0,0,0), (*bx,by,bz*) and (*cx,cy,cz*) as vertices.

Define the vector

**u** = (*bx,by,bz*)

pointing from A to B, and normalise it to the unit vector

**U** = ( 1 /|**u**|) **u**  =  ( 1 / √( *bx*^2 + *by*^2 + *bz*^2 ) )  (*bx,by,bz*)

Take the cross product

**w** = **u** × (*cx,cy,cz*),

which is at right angles to the triangle.
Normalise it to give the unit vector

**W** = ( 1 /|**w**|) **w** .

Find the cross-product

**V** = **U**  ×**W** ,

automatically a unit vector.

In coordinates corresponding to the basis {**U**, **V**,  **W** }, the triangle lies as you want. The rotation matrix that carries the usual (1,0,0) to **U**,  the usual (0,1,0) to **V**, and the usual (,0,0,1) to **W** has **U**, **V** and **W** as its columns.  You want the other direction, so take the inverse — which for a rotation matrix is just the transpose.

This is not "**the** transformation for the above case", because you did not specify whether C should lie on the *y*>0 half plane.

Comment: So I basically have to convert the local coordinate system of the triangle to put it in the global coordinate, right? Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am giving you a concrete example with numbers. Suppose my three vertex are A(-8.61, 1.80, 19.31), B(-5.99, -0.72, 21.51), C(-8.88, 5.05, 20.67). I want to transform ABC such a way that A becomes (0, 0, 0), B becomes (4.25, 0, 0) and C becomes (-1.39, -3.24, 0 ) something like that. So C can be y < 0 too. Now from the calculation you have given how can I derive the rotation and translation component?